# Return action items not in event table for all people - complex select where not exist

Tags: sql, sql-server

I feel like this should be an easy solve, but for I can't seem to solve this one.

Here are some sample tables and data.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[people](
    [PersonID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO people (PersonID, Name) VALUES (1, 'Bob')
INSERT INTO people (PersonID, Name) VALUES (2, 'Bill')
INSERT INTO people (PersonID, Name) VALUES (3, 'Ben')

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[events](
    [PersonID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ActionID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [EventDate] [date] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

-- Bob goes from sitting to running step by step
INSERT INTO events (PersonID, ActionID, EventDate) VALUES (1, 1, getdate()-3)
INSERT INTO events (PersonID, ActionID, EventDate) VALUES (1, 2, getdate()-2)
INSERT INTO events (PersonID, ActionID, EventDate) VALUES (1, 3, getdate()-1)
INSERT INTO events (PersonID, ActionID, EventDate) VALUES (1, 4, getdate())

-- Bill goes from sitting to walking, still waiting to run
INSERT INTO events (PersonID, ActionID, EventDate) VALUES (2, 1, getdate()-2)
INSERT INTO events (PersonID, ActionID, EventDate) VALUES (2, 2, getdate()-1)
INSERT INTO events (PersonID, ActionID, EventDate) VALUES (2, 3, getdate())

-- Ben manages to go from sitting to running without standing or walking
INSERT INTO events (PersonID, ActionID, EventDate) VALUES (3, 1, getdate()-3)
INSERT INTO events (PersonID, ActionID, EventDate) VALUES (3, 4, getdate())

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[actions](
    [ActionID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO actions (ActionID, Name) VALUES (1, 'Sit')
INSERT INTO actions (ActionID, Name) VALUES (2, 'Stand')
INSERT INTO actions (ActionID, Name) VALUES (3, 'Walk')
INSERT INTO actions (ActionID, Name) VALUES (4, 'Run')
```

What I'm trying to get is a list of all actions which do not have events for each user.

With the data above, I'd expect results like ...

```
|----------+----------|
| PersonID | ActionID |
|----------+----------|
|    2     |    4     |
|----------+----------|
|    3     |    2     |
|----------+----------|
|    3     |    3     |
|----------+----------|
```

I can do it for a specified person with something like ...

```
-- Get a list of actions that do not have an event for each user
SELECT 
  actions.ActionID, 
  events.PersonID 
FROM 
  actions 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN events on events.ActionID = actions.ActionID 
  AND events.PersonID = 3 
WHERE 
  events.PersonID IS NULL
```

But I'd really like to pull this out for all users without subqueries per user or cursors, etc.

The more I think about it, the less I think it can be done.

Any suggestions would be great.

Thanks. ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/85f6c/8/0))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach can be using `EXCEPT`

```
SELECT PersonId, ActionId FROM [dbo].[people], [dbo].[actions]
EXCEPT
SELECT PersonId,ActionId FROM [dbo].[events]
```

Same using ANSI syntax

```
SELECT PersonId, ActionId FROM  [dbo].[people] CROSS JOIN [dbo].[actions]
EXCEPT
SELECT PersonId,ActionId FROM [dbo].[events]
```

You can also do it using `NOT EXISTS` like following.

```
SELECT P.PersonId, A.ActionId FROM  [dbo].[people] P CROSS JOIN [dbo].[actions] A
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
 SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].[events] E WHERE P.PersonID= E.PersonID AND A.ActionID= E.ActionID
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution to your problem:

```
SELECT p.PersonID,a.ActionID
FROM people p
CROSS JOIN  actions a
LEFT JOIN Events e
ON p.PersonId = e.PersonID AND a.actionID = e.actionID
WHERE EventDate IS NULL;
```

Follow the link to the demo:

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6b49b/19

Used Cross Join to generate all combinations of `Person` and `Action` 
and then Used `LEFT JOIN` with `Events` to check which action is done by which person and selected those people and actions which didn't happen by using `IS NULL`.